# What does $(a,b) = 1$ mean in the context of the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$?

Tags: notation, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

I was reading a proof for $\sqrt 2$ (which is a standard easy proof), but I came across a notation I've never seen. It says this:

> If $ \sqrt 2$ is rational then the equation 
>   $$ a^2  = 2 b^2 $$
>   is soluble in integers $a,b$ with $(a,b) = 1$.

What does that mean?

> soluble in integers $a,b$ with $(a,b) = 1$.

I am just unfamiliar with the notation. I am sure it's easy.

---

All proof:

[image]

source: http://www.cs.kun.nl/~freek/notes/sketches.pdf

Comment: $(a,b)$ means the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The origin of this notation comes from the fact that  the g.c.d. is the positive generator of the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$, commonly denoted by $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Bernard I don't know what ideals are. Makes sense why I didn't understand it. Im not a mathematician.

Comment: @Bernard a answer with those details would be appreciated but not pressure.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘pressure’?

Comment: @Bernard: I didn't knew that, but it really make sense. Thank you very much for your comment :)

Comment: Do you know (even little) about vector spaces  and subspaces?

Comment: @Bernard pressure I meant that don't feel obliged to write up my request, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression "$a^2=2b^2$ is soluble in integers $a,b$ with $(a,b)=1$" is simply another way of saying that there exists a solution $(a,b)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: can you make a comment about ideals and generators for the origin of the notation?

Comment: Ideals are sets of the form $\{nx : x\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $R$ be a ring. Then we have that the set $\{pa+qb : p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is the generator of the ideal $(a,b)$. Note that this set is equivalent to $\{dx : x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $d=\gcd(a,b)$. You can see this using Bezout's Lemma, which states that if $d=\gcd(a,b)$, there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $pa+qb=d$. Hope this helps.

Comment: in your definition of ideals it seems there is an assumed arithmetic on tuples? Or what is $n$? I am confused what "generator of ideal (a,b)" means.

Comment: $n$ is just an arbitrary integer, chosen before $x$. The statement "generator of the ideal (a,b)" simply means that it produces the values of the ideal $(a,b)$. This ideal can be thought of as a "2-D" ideal, using the definition for ideals that I gave. Does this help?